# How to find Label of a input field

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

Looking for a generic way to find text before an input field to know what to fill in the field. Using xpath, css selector or any other way possible.

```
<div>
    <span>Full Name</span>
    <input name="xddadN">
</div>
<div>
    <span>Email</span>
    <input name="xedadN">
</div>
```

Or

```
<div>
    <div><label>Full Name</label></div>
    <div><input name="xddadN"></div>
    <div><label>Email</label></div>
    <div><input name="xedadN"></
</div>
```

Or

```
<div>
    <label>Full Name<br>
    <span><input name="xddadN"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Full Name<br>
    <span><input name="xddadN"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: you wanna extract <span>Full Name</span> and <span>Email</span> values ?

Comment: Yes. But I want a generic way so that it doesn't have to be a `<span>` basically any text before an input field.

Comment: I don't think so you can write a generic locator for that. span here is nothing but a preceding-sibling

Comment: And in your second case it's label , so there is no point of generalization, you can do !

Comment: First, you can't detect all kind of text before an `input` field, it's very hard;
Second, the best way to find the logic content of an `input` field is using the attribute of the field (such as `name`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below XPath expression to [get preceding text node](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%3EFull%20Name%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20name%3D%22xddadN%22%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%3EEmail%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20name%3D%22xedadN%22%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%3Clabel%3EFull%20Name%3C%2Flabel%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%3Cinput%20name%3D%22xddadN%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%3Clabel%3EEmail%3C%2Flabel%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%3Cinput%20name%3D%22xedadN%22%3E%3C%2F%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Finput%2Fpreceding%3A%3A*%5B1%5D%2Ftext()&=%2Ftext()&input-format=html&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xquery1):

```
//input/preceding::*[1]
```

or more specific for Full Name

```
//input[@name="xddadN"]/preceding::*[1]
```

and Email:

```
//input[@name="xedadN"]/preceding::*[1]
```

Comment: @Anderson  If this works , then I think it would be generic.

Comment: @Anderson This worked like a charm. For a more nested field and labels we can increase the value in the bracket until we find a text.

Answer (score 0):

For full name use this Xpath : **//input[@name='xddadN']/preceding-sibling::span**

**code** :

```
String fullName = driver.findElement(By.Xpath(//input[@name='xddadN']/preceding-sibling::span)).getText();  

String Email = driver.findElement(By.Xpath(//input[@name='xedadN']/preceding-sibling::span)).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned any *Selenium Language Binding Art* so I will be using *Java* for the example.

### First the Answer

**Yes**, you can use a generic way to find text before an input field as follows :

- As per the HTML :

  ```
  <div>
      <span>Full Name</span>
      <input name="xddadN">
  </div>
  <div>
      <span>Email</span>
      <input name="xedadN">
  </div>
  ```
- To retrieve the text **Full Name** from the `<span>` tag with respect to the `<input>` tag you can use :

  ```
  String myText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='xddadN']//preceding::*[1]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```

### Now the Pitfall

Without any visibility to your *usecase* in my opinion the *generic way* would be a **pitfall** which will induce much **chaos** and **uncertanity** for the following reasons :

- As per the *xpath* we are straightway jumping into the previous element, a small change in the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) (e.g. inclusion of a `<span>` tag) will make your *Testcases* to **Fail**.
- In general, while constructing a *Locator Strategy* through *css-selectors* or *xpath* it will be benificial to include the `<tagName>` to **optimize** the *element search process*. If `<tagName>` are not included your *Tests* will require more time to locate the elements and perform action on them. In this process you are compromising some of the advantages of **Test Automation**.

### Conclusion

Hence as a conclusion as per the *Best Practices* always include the `<tagName>` while constructing a *Locator Strategy* through *css-selectors* or *xpath*.